# Как выполнить запрос Mysql если в поле есть символ решетки?

Tags: mysql

При запросе просто на выборку и базы Mysql в одном из полей в условии может появляться решетка в строке поиска, можно ли ее как-то экранировать? Ниже запросы, отсекается все что после решетки
Пример запроса выполняется:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year AS row FROM oc_podbor WHERE brands LIKE 'LEXUS' AND model LIKE '%GS Hybrid (GRL1%'
```

хотелось бы

```
SELECT DISTINCT year AS row FROM oc_podbor WHERE brands LIKE 'LEXUS' AND model LIKE '%GS Hybrid (GRL1#123)%'
```

Comment: Символ решётки не требует никаких дополнительных телодвижений в запросе - обычный символ. Если он вызывает проблемы - это не MySQL виноват.

Comment: Похоже вы правы, приходит уже урезано.